# Howto disable horizontal scroll movement on a scrollview?

Tags: android, scrollview, overlay

I have a vertical scrollview that scrolls vertically each element.

The problem is that those elements layout goes outside the screen, causing the scroll to move in horizontal direction, over the normal vertical one.

I want to block this behavior letting only scroll vertically.

[image: 1]
<sub>(source: [naturalware.eu](https://www.naturalware.eu/scroll.jpg))</sub>

RE:
isn't the problem of the overlay. I just tested with Layout that have a width of a couple of pixels and it continue scroll horizontally. The important thing is that this `ScrollView` is wrapped into a `ViewPager` and notwhistand I blocked the touch event it still scroll horizonatally: that makes sense.

```
    mPager = findViewById(R.id.menu_wrapper_content);
    mAdapter = new ActivityMain.MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mPager.setCurrentItem(0, false);//##NUM

    mPager.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
        {
            return true;
        }
    });

    mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(10);
```

Comment: Android's ScrollView only scrolls vertically. Show your layout.

Comment: if the width of the views under the scroll view is more than the width of your phone, it will scroll horizontally too. You have to change your individual views so that all elements under it will fit under the phones width

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.